# Picturefill not working in Internet Explorer; not recognizing srcset?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, picturefill

I've used Picturefill to load a couple of images on my web page. They display correctly in Chrome but don't display at all in Internet Explorer 8.

Here is a sample of my code:

```
<link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="js/modernizr.custom.11641.js"></script>
<script async="true" src="js/picturefill.js"></script>
<script src="js/respond.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="wrapper">
    <header class="x-padding inside-b-padding">
        <h1 class="nocontent outline">Baseball for Busy
        People</h1>


    <picture class="logo">
        <!--[if IE 9]><video style="display: none;"><![endif]-->
        <source srcset="images/logo.png" media="(min-width: 750px)">
        <!--[if IE 9]></video><![endif]-->
        <img srcset="images/logo-small.png" alt="Baseball for Busy People">
    </picture>
```

(I'm including the top part in case my file linking is part of the problem).

I can view the demo in IE 8: http://scottjehl.github.io/picturefill/examples/demo-02.html. But the images on my page aren't working.

Here is what I tried:

1. I copied and pasted the code from the demo into my page (changing the image paths to absolute) - they did not display.
2. I added script to create a `<picture>` element (although I'm using Modernizr, so it should not be needed).
3. I added a src path to the img tag, which worked, but I read that Picturefill doesn't recommend this.

Comment: As a first port of call I would look into your media blocks as I see you are using respond.js. Just incase you are accidentally hiding anthing for IE8. The above code you supplied looks ok to me so not sure why on this one - can you provide a codepen? Also may want to consider adding below this block a <noscript> with a standard <img src="".

Answer (score 6):

I know this question was asked a long time ago, but maybe this will help others who run into similar issue. I had the same problem where Picturefill images were not loading on my website in browsers that don't support it natively (IE9 - IE11, for example). The fix was to make sure that picturefill() was called when the element was added to the page (I called it in a directive in Angular, and componentDidMount in React).

Comment: you sir, are my hero. I was toggling some items via javascript and in IE11, the pictures weren't loading, so this is still a problem. You're answer worked for me.

Comment: This answer is gold. `componentDidMount()` is the key for anyone having this issue with React.